# can Amazon be used to offload server of static files for a Ruby on Rails app, but still support the app's authentication & authorization?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, amazon-s3

Can one of the Amazon services (their S3 data service, or otherwise) be used to offload server of static files for a Ruby on Rails app, but still support the app's authentication & authorization?

That is such that when the user browser downloaded the initial HTML for one page of the Ruby on Rails application, when it went back for static content (e.g. an image or CSS file), that this request would be:
(a) routed directly to the Amazon service (no RoR cycles used to serve it, or bandwidth), BUT
(b) the browser request for this item (e.g. an image) would still have to go through an authentication/authorization layer based on the user model in the Ruby on Rails application - in other words to ensure not just anyone could get the image...

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is a yes with a but.  You can use a feature of S3 that allows you to create links to secure S3 objects that has a small time to live, default is 5 minutes.  This will work for any S3 object that is uploaded as private.  This means that the browser will only have X seconds or whatever to request the file from S3.  Example code from [docs](http://amazon.rubyforge.org/) for the AWS gem:

```
S3Object.url_for('beluga_baby.jpg', 'marcel_molina')
```

You can also specify an expires_in or expires option per file.  The bad thing is that you would need to create a helper for your stylesheet, image, and js links to create the proper S3 URLs. 
I would recommend that you setup a domain name for your S3 bucket, like "examples3.amazonaws.com" and put all your standard image files and CSS there as public.  Then set that as the asset host in your rails config.  Then, only use the secure links for static files that really need it.